# Magento Customer Sign up page layout simple issue

Tags: magento

I seem to have a simple layout issue with out customer signup page @ http://www.skylanternsworld.com/shop/index.php/customer/account/create/

You can see the text boxes and header text is a little muddled up. I have looked through the files but cannot see where I would fix this. Can someone please direct me to the file that I need to edit to fix this, I think maybe it is just a spacing or css issue but I really not sure and tests we have tried did not work.

Running magento 1.6.2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the admin area go to System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer.  If you change the current configuration scope to your theme, you'll see an option under the Debug tab to turn on template and block hints.  This will give you the location of the various templates that make up the page.